# How can I refresh an OLAP table in the background? I have a table in powerpivot that is linked to a SQL database

Tags: excel, powerpivot, olap-cube

Please can you assist me? I have a table on Powerpivot that is linked to a SQL database. I'd like it to refresh even when the file is closed so that when users read the dashboard that's linked to the dataset, its the latest version.

Please can you help me? I have Excel 2013. Can Excel 2016 run background refresh? Thanks in advance :)

[image: Connection settings on the Excel workbook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in Excel 2016, you have to have the file open to update the power pivot model.

Your only real options are either write some VBA which opens the file  runs the update, then saves and closes the file.  Then have that run on a schedule.

The VBA involved would be below which loads the model, then refreshes it

```
ThisWorkbook.Model.Initialize
ThisWorkbook.Model.Refresh
```

The other option, though I have never used it, is Power Update which is a third party program for automating Power Pivot updates.
Link to a blog post talking about it:
https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/02/introducing-power-update/

Comment: Thanks you so much :)